# If else errors in C

Tags: c

guys, I need help I'm new in programming and I have problems with the if-else statement

I tried deleting every "paragraph" that contains the word else/else if and it worked only for the if "paragraph" though(obviously cuz the others aren't there)

float w,l,r,pi,rec,tri,cir;
    char shape;

```
printf("What shape is the desired calculated area?\n");
scanf("%c",&shape);

    if(shape=='R')
    printf("width: ");
    scanf("%f",&w);
    printf("length: ");
    scanf("%f",&l);
    rec=w*l;
    printf("\nThe area for the rectangle is %.2f Cm2\n",rec);

    else if(shape=='C')
    printf("radius: ");
    scanf("%f",&r);
    pi=3.142;
    cir=pi*r*r;
    printf("\nThe area for the rectangle is %.2f Cm2\n",cir);

    else if(shape=='T')
    printf("width: ");
    scanf("%f",&w);
    printf("length: ");
    scanf("%f",&l);
    tri=1/2*w*l;
    printf("\nThe area for the rectangle is %.2f Cm2\n",tri);

    else
    printf("You must choose one type of shape using R C T only and only digits are allowed afterwards");
```

I got a message which is [Error]  parse error before `else' for every line that contains the word else. Further reading of the error message says error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're missing curly brackets.  `if (...) { /* conditional stuff goes here /* } else if { /* and here... */ }`.  If you skip the curly brackets only the next statement is conditional, so for your first block `printf("width: ");` is conditionally executed, the next statement (`scanf("%f",&w);`) is **always** executed.

Comment: The C language has no notion of "paragraphs".  A blank line is treated the same as a single space (or a sequence of spaces).  To create a compound statement, use curly braces `{}`.  Also, learn to indent your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using {} if your line more than one when you use "if"
like

```
if(shape=='R'){
    printf("width: ");
    scanf("%f",&w);
    printf("length: ");
    scanf("%f",&l);
    rec=w*l;
    printf("\nThe area for the rectangle is %.2f Cm2\n",rec);
}
```

---

```
if(shape=='R')
printf("width: ");
scanf("%f",&w);
printf("length: ");
scanf("%f",&l);
rec=w*l;
printf("\nThe area for the rectangle is %.2f Cm2\n",rec);
```

Will be like below in compiler

```
if(shape=='R'){
    printf("width: ");
}
scanf("%f",&w);
printf("length: ");
scanf("%f",&l);
rec=w*l;
printf("\nThe area for the rectangle is %.2f Cm2\n",rec);
```